# SQLCommand, create table

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

I want to create table in my database after button click. In Button_Click function I have a code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"MyConnectionString");

conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE '" + tableName+ "' (IdPy INT IDENTITY(1,1), Question NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL, IsChecked BIT NOT NULL,  CONSTRAINTPK_'" + tableName+ "' PRIMARY KEY(Id) )", conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

`tableName` is my `String` variable (its value `2018-04-18 asd` - yes, I want the table with such a name). And I have an error after button click:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '2018-04-18 asd'.'

I think that the problem is in my SqlCommand. I would be gratefull if you could help me solve that problem.

Comment: Did you check the text of the SqlCommand through a debugger?

Comment: Please, check `tableName` value (put a breakpoint)

Comment: you may find you need to put [] round the table name not single quotes

Comment: My tableName value is "2018-04-18 asd"

Comment: Check CONSTRAINTPK_'" + tableName+ "' ... That would lead to CONSTRAINTPK_'myTable'

Comment: If you insist on `2018-04-18 ast` table name you should put `"CONSTRAINTPK_ + tableName + "`

Comment: Add watch and get string from it

Comment: @PaulKaram He/she can. As long as it is correctly escaped (which is faling, check my previous comment)

Comment: @bradbury9 yeah, hence I deleted my comment.

Comment: You have a second mistake, it should be `constraint constraint_name`, you are missing an space besides the wrong escaping. Check the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-column-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `tableName` variable is `2018-04-18 asd`. If that really is the correct table name, you need to escape it (and the constraint) in square brackets:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE [" + tableName + "] (IdPy INT IDENTITY(1,1), Question NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL, IsChecked BIT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT [CONSTRAINTPK_" + tableName+ "] PRIMARY KEY(Id) )", conn);
```

Comment: I got this error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The definition for column 'CONSTRAINTPK_2018-04-18asd' must include a data type.'

Comment: @MrNobody I wonder if you did miss an space `BIT NOT NULL,  CONSTRAINT_MISSING_SPACE_PK_`

Comment: @bradbury9 You are right. It work's. Thank you for your feedback. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should **escape** (`[...]` in case of MS SQL) *table* and *constraint* names:

```
  //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
  using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"MyConnectionString")) {
    conn.Open();

    //DONE: Make sql readable. Can you see that you've skipped CONSTRAINT keyword?
    string sql = 
      $@"CREATE TABLE [{tableName}] (
           -- Fields
           IdPy      INT IDENTITY(1,1),
           Question  NVARCHAR (MAX)     NOT NULL, 
           IsChecked BIT                NOT NULL,

           -- Constraints
           --DONE: Constraint key word (optional in some RDBMS) added 
           CONSTRAINT [CONSTRAINTPK_{tableName}] PRIMARY KEY(Id) 
         )";

    //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
    using (qlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to identify issues with your SQLCommand by using a string variable and parameterised string formatting. An example:

```
string query = "CREATE TABLE @tablename (IdPy INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
Question NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL, IsChecked BIT NOT NULL,  
CONSTRAINTPK_@tablename PRIMARY KEY(Id) )";

string param = new {@tablename = txttable.txt(example)};

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, param, conn);
```

This might help step through to make sure that the variable you have to inspect more concise.